# Are late comments requesting jsFiddle links in answers really okay?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags, jsfiddle

I recently received a comment under an older (2012), jQuery UI-related answer of mine. The [comment in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339601/jquery-ui-slider-with-string-values/11339769#comment56137612_11339769) only consisted in:

> please share a working fiddle

I had a hard time understanding the rationale behind that request, given that:

- [The question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11339601/464709) did not contain either HTML markup or a fiddle link, and did not need that to stand on its own,
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339769/464709) was also self-contained, built upon the questioner's code, and can also stand on its own I believe,
- There is enough context in both the question and the answer for the commenter to create a fiddle themselves if they are so inclined,
- The code in my answer works (and still works, I double-checked), so this wasn't an indirect way for the commenter to bring my attention to a wrong answer,
- We've had Stack Snippets for a while now, so requesting an external fiddle seemed quite odd to me.

I could have replied to the comment, possibly along the lines of *Can't you make one yourself?*, but it would not have been nice. I could have ignored it, and that was tempting, but I was worried about the [broken windows effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) since I did not believe such a comment to be constructive in the first place. So I went ahead and flagged the comment as *not constructive*.

The flag was declined.

So now I'm wondering if comments like this are actually welcome here. For a while now I have observed a trend in JavaScript questions, where some users always request a "working fiddle" even if the question can readily be answered (sometimes even on obvious typo-related questions). I personally do not wish the same thing to happen in *answers* too.

What do you think?

Comment: Its unreasonable to have an author expend extra energy of at best dubious benefit to future readers just to include a "working fiddle" (which, incidentally, always makes me think of music instruments)

Comment: I usually have good luck with "not constructive" on comments like that.  I suspect you were just unlucky.  Or it was because the request included the word "please", that's not very common.  It is an unreasonable request after this long and you are certainly not obligated to follow up, feel free to just ignore it.  Otherwise an ungentle reminder that we do have to support answers for the rest of our natural life.  Oh joy.

Comment: On a different note, that other Answer to the question is atrocious.

Comment: User in question seem to be trying to get working sample of particular control based on other comments they made... I see no reasons to accommodate the request. (added comment to the comment in original question).

Comment: Maybe link them to a Lindsey Sterling video next time?

Comment: they're comments, who cares.

Comment: I don't do JS, but I occasionally get comments on old answers for other languages saying "please demonstrate this in code". My gut feeling is usually that it's someone who doesn't understand the answer (which might be either my fault or their fault) and is hoping to get something they can copy and paste (which if true I consider their fault). If they ask me to explain a specific point that's unclear then I usually respond, perhaps even in code form. But "plz to give codez" I ignore.

Comment: "We've had Stack Snippets for a while now, so requesting an external fiddle seemed quite odd to me." Usually, I chalk this up to the word "fiddle" being much like "google" - it's a [genericized name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark) (not sure if "fiddle" is a proper trademark but the principle is the same). They probably don't care as long as it's a live demo.

Comment: FWIW, I would have removed the comment for being a late, lazy comment on an old answer alone as you said. The date of an answer with flags is immediately visible in the queue without jumping through any hoops, so it wouldn't have taken me more than a single click to determine this.

Answer (score 13):

The comment as such is merely a request for clarification/feedback on your answer. As such it's not really unconstructive per se. You may well respond to it to provide a Fiddle or Snippet and that would actually improve your answer. So, declining the flag was correct.

Having said that, it *is* pretty unreasonable of the commenter to a) request such a thing after such a long time and b) do it in the way they did. If there was something unclear about your answer, they could have specifically asked about that, and perhaps asked for a working, running sample to help them diagnose the problem in their understanding. But as it is, ignoring is the most valid response to such an absurd request.

If you want to respond to them, ask them what issue they have in using your answer as is, and perhaps open a new question about this issue specifically.

Comment: I'm not really in tune with your first sentence. I understand adding a fiddle link is almost always a positive thing to do, but in this specific case I believe both the question and the answer are clear enough to stand on their own (the questioner even linked to the demo page they used as a starting point). So, to me, declining the flag was not that correct. YMMV anyway :)

Comment: I'm not saying that the request for clarification was ***warranted***. To me your answer indeed looks just fine without it. However, that's still what the comment is.

Comment: Anyone is free to ask for clarifications on the most clear posts. It just makes them look like a dolt when they do.

Comment: Indeed that appears to be the net effect :) I agree everyone is free to leave comments that make them look like dolts, but are such comments really constructive, in the sense that they should be left there? Wouldn't the commenter look less like a dolt if the comment was removed?

Comment: We've got plenty of people looking like dolts on the site, we can't possibly remove them all... :o)

Comment: I disagree with the comment being a request for clarification,it was "gimme the codez" and nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

I agree the comment is noise and doesn't help in improving the post. However, asking for a fiddle is often warranted and I can imagine that a moderator couldn't quickly grasp why that wouldn't be constructive, hence they choose to err on the safe side and declined your flag.

A similar flagging procedure as I use for Not an Answer flags might have helped. If you suspect the moderator needs more context to be able to handle this in one click without visiting both question and answer you better use a custom reason explaining the context.

As you don't see the need for an fiddle or taking the time to create one I see no problem in leaving a comment explaining that to the user and invite them to create a StackSnippet to be added to the answer. It might turn out that they don't understand your answer or they leave that same comment on every answer without a fiddle or they are hunting for the *leave 1000 comments before Christmas hat*...

By simply flagging the site gets cleaned, sure. But the user leaving that comment didn't learn a thing.

Comment: I was wondering about using a custom flag, yes, but I was under the (possibly wrong) impression that *not constructive* summarized what I had to say quite clearly. As for the user not learning anything about their behavior, you have a good point, but I'm struggling to find a way to express my concerns that would not be considered as hostile by the commenter. Maybe a link to this meta post would do.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You could always say something as *I didn't think it was needed when I created the answer two years ago and atm I'm a little bit short on time. Feel free to have a go at it and I'm happy to approve an edit if you add the Stack Snippet*. I don't think there is rudeness in that, but linking to this meta-post may also help.

Comment: @rene IMO that sounds way more defensive than it needs to be. While I certainly agree that you mustn't be rude, there's also no need to bend over backwards for random comments on the interweb.

Comment: @deceze I'm a flower, I can bend in many different ways ... until you brake me....

Comment: @rene: The whole point of asking someone else for a fiddle is that they can't or won't build it themselves. Such a response would be counter-productive as it'd likely result in an unnecessary back-and-forth - on top of being a colossal waste of time to type.

Answer (score 0):

Requests for jsfiddles/codepens should be banned IMO. S.O. has a snippet feature. S.O requires a minimal reproducible example in the question. Requesting a jsfiddle/codepen is basically admitting the question didn't have a "minimal reproducible example" and is therefore off topic.

As for answers, arguably the same should apply. If you're going to provide working code put it in a snippet where it will stick around and where others can edit it if it breaks vs some offset place where it could disappear and no one can fix it. Commenters should request a snippet, not a fiddle/codepen.